# Does the GROUP BY occur after the operations that occur in the SELECT statement? (BigQuery)

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, order-of-execution

From what I have read on e.g. `https://www.sisense.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations/` I understand that SQL statements will execute in the order:

1: FROM, 2: WHERE, 3: GROUP BY, 4: HAVINIG, 5: SELECT, 6: ORDER BY, 7: LIMIT

This makes sense to me, except for the fact that you can GROUP BY new columns created in the SELECT statement. e.g.

```
WITH data_sample AS (
   SELECT "m1" as meter, 2 as value UNION ALL 
   SELECT "m1" as meter, 3 as value, UNION ALL 
   SELECT "m1" as meter, 5 as value, UNION ALL
   SELECT "m1" as meter, 5 as value UNION ALL
   SELECT "m2" as meter, 4 as value UNION ALL
   SELECT "m2" as meter, 6 as value UNION ALL 
   SELECT "m3" as meter, 4 as value UNION ALL
   SELECT "m3" as meter, 4 as value )


SELECT IF(meter="m1", meter, "m7") as meter_new, SUM(value)
FROM data_sample
GROUP BY meter_new
```

Here the new column, `meter_new` that is created in the SELECT statement, is already available to the GROUP BY (which makes me think that SELECT executes before the GROUP BY) but this grouping is then used for the SUM statement which is in the SELECT part of the query making it seem that the SELECT is happening after the GROUP BY as well.

Clearly I am missing something here, but googling just keeps returning the same ordered list of operations which is not helping me.

Comment: Strictly, you can't GROUP BY columns created in the SELECT clause. But some products cheat here...

Comment: You can't exactly talk about SQL statement execution order - SQL servers are free to make suboperations in any order or parallel, just result needs to be correct.

Comment: About your problem - most likely bigquery replaces `meter_new` with its source expression (`IF(meter="m1", meter, "m7")`) from select part of query. Not a standard SQL feature.

Comment: @Arvo, this trick useb by google big quetry and MySQL is mostly stupid, beacuse if any column in the table used by the query had a name that is exactly the alias name given in the SELECT cause for the expression, there will be a confusion...

Comment: Hi @164_user Do this [link1](https://youtu.be/q9npE47O2UI) and [link2](https://towardsdatascience.com/5-bigquery-sql-performance-tips-for-modern-data-scientists-f880b79cfa71) help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The execution order of BigQuery is totally different from general RDBMS.**

BigQuery uses the Dremel query engine to execute queries.Dremel uses a multi-level serving tree to execute queries . A root server receives incoming queries, reads metadata from the tables, and routes the queries to the next level in the serving tree. You can read more about how BigQuery works from this  [link1](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36632.pdf) and [link2](https://youtu.be/UueWySREWvk).

You can check the execution order of your query using [Query Plan Explanation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation).

[image]